# controller return empty Json value

Tags: laravel

i want to see the json value of my DB 
my controller

```
public function index() {  
$pt=Post::all();
return response()->json($pt);
}
```

my route

```
Route::get('/list','posts_user@index');
```

Comment: Paste the `Controller` code here please.

Comment: You really think this is readable? Update your question

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in

```php
$post=new Post;   // you used NEW in place of new
```

```php
public function create(Request $request){ 
        $post=new Post; 
        $post->titre=$request->get('titre');
        $post->status=$request->get('post');
        $post->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $post->save();
        return response()->json([ "post" => $post ]);
    }
```

Comment: same problem , the value saved in DB but when i use this root "/list" Json list is empty

Comment: try to send array in response return response()->json([ "post" => $post ]);